Make video without select webcam
I am trying to make a video without having to select the camera and resolution through the form but I am not succeeding.
This way works but with the form.
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                
                FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            }
            ButtonRecStart.PerformClick();
            
        }

       public void ButtonRecStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenVideoSource(FinalVideo);
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }


I tried differents things, here show some of them...
        private void kryptonButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection[2].MonikerString);

            //FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(LoaclWebCamsCollection[2].MonikerString);
            //OpenVideoSource(FinalVideo);
            //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            //FinalVideo.Start();
            CerrarWebCam();
            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[2].MonikerString);
            OpenVideoSource(FinalVideo);
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
    

                
            //int i = 2;
            //string NombreVideo = miDispositivos[i].MonikerString;
            //FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(NombreVideo);
            ////miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            ////miWebcam.Start();

            //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }

